# How to get the facebook comment sorter to appear?

Tags: facebook

I've been banging my head against the wall for ages now but I just can't get the facebook comment sorter to appear above my comments.
It usually says something like '21 Comments' and has a drop down that allows you to change the sort order of the comments.

I can see it working on other people's facebook pages, it just won't appear on mine :(

I have this code from all the documentation I've read:

```
<div class="fb-comments"
data-href="http://www.facebook.com/app_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
data-colorscheme="dark" data-num-posts="3" data-width="440"
data-order-by="reverse_time"></div>
```

But still I get no sorter, just the comment box and the last 3 comments.
Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are the other people pointing the comments plugin at a correctly marked up URL? yours appears to be pointing at something on facebook.com which is almost certainly incorrect

Comment: Thanks Igy, I copied something I found there. Do you know what the URL should point at? Is it a file containing anything in particular?

Comment: It's supposed to be the URL of the article people are commenting on, with [meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) to tell Facebook's crawler how to display links to that URL